# Using external cmake executable in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

I would like my Android Studio project to use a different version of cmake than the one installed in Android Studio.

I added a variable

```
cmake.dir=C\:\\path\\to\\a\\different\\cmake
```

to my local.properties file, and this location is used for some of the compilation of my project but not all.

In the logs of my project build, I still see references to the cmake version installed in AS, and for example, in build_model.json under apps.cxx\cmake\debug\x86, I see:

```
"cmakeExecutable":
"C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.10.2.4988404\\bin\\cmake.exe",
```

What other file/setting do I need to change so that AS uses *exclusively* an external verison of cmake for all compilation?